# Google Apps Script - Gmail - Can't detect a certain string reliably in spam emails

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, gmail

I've been using this script to automatically purge the insane amounts of spam from my Gmail every 5 minutes.

```
function annihilateSpam() {
  var keywords = ["storage.googleapis.com", "bit.ly", "shoutout.wix.com"]
  var email = 'me@gmail.com'
  var threads = GmailApp.getSpamThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++)
    {
      var message = messages[j];
      var body = message.getRawContent();
      for (var k = 0; k < keywords.length; k++)
      {
        if (body.indexOf(keywords[k])>-1)
        {
          try {
            Logger.log(threads[i].getFirstMessageSubject() + " detected keyword: " + keywords[k]); 
            Gmail.Users.Messages.remove(email, messages[j].getId());
            //Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(email, threads[i].getId());
          }
          catch (err) {
            Logger.log("Error " + err.message);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the bit.ly keyword not working reliably. From the last 16 hours there are 40 new emails all containing numerous bit.ly links and they are not being deleted when the script runs. Other emails containing bit.ly links still get deleted as they should, same result if they contain anything else that's in the keyword array. I can add any other text contained within these problem emails to the keywords array and they will get deleted as they should. But "bit.ly" only gets detected for certain emails, not any of the ones I've received today/recently.

All I need the script to do is permanently delete anything in the spam folder that matches any of the keywords. If there's an easier or more reliable way I'm all for it. I'd like to keep using the array since it's easy to add keywords to filter, no additional code blocks every time I want to add a keyword.

Some example logs

```
May 10, 2021, 2:36:16 AM
Info
 -   detected keyword: 3b***PR
```

```
May 10, 2021, 3:22:14 AM
Info
Mortgage Added $15.000 to your retirement account   #89ax detected keyword: storage.googleapis.com
```

Update: So there's a bunch of garbage text in these emails, but it's the same for all of them. Still no idea why bit.ly doesn't work on these but adding some of that filler text to the keywords got them all to go away.

Comment: Just a thought.  I've been down the path you're on with spam and I finally came to the conclusion that it's easier to keep track of the emails that I want and just eliminate all the others.  I keep track of the from,to, and subject of all the emails just to be able to catch the few that I might want to add to my current emails but I find that a lot easier than trying to figure out how to write an effect spam filter.  Personally, I've  never found one that works as good as the script I have now that simply rejects everything that's not in my current email list.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue with differing letter case. One way to match keywords to a text string in a case-insensitive fashion is with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html), like this:

```
  var keywords = /storage\.googleapis\.com|bit\.ly|shoutout\.wix\.com/i;
  // ...
  // keyword loop not needed   for (var k = 0; k < keywords.length; k++) {
      if (body.match(keywords)) {
      // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've made these changes in the editor, now we wait for more spam to see if it changes anything.